# How do I point to a function in the code behind file for a razor page from an ajax call in that same page?

Tags: asp.net-core

I keep getting 404s. The file is at `Admin/UploadConfirmation.cshtml`. The URL is `localhost:444/Admin/UploadConfirmation`. The function is called `CopyData`.

But when I try to make an ajax call against it, it just 404s.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Admin/UploadConfirmation/CopyData"
```

How do I make an ajax call from the cshtml file to its own cshtml.cs file?

Comment: looks like you use area and don't have conventional routing configuration for area (of course not having attribute routing either).

Comment: You can't use attribute routing with razor pages. I'm not familiar with areas.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make an ajax call from the cshtml file to its own cshtml.cs
> file?

Please refer the following steps and sample code:

1. In the Razor application, create an Admin areas and add an Index page:

   [image]
2. Configure the Areas page route and antiforgery service.

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages() 
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Admin", "/Index", "Admin");
            }); 
        services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");  //configure the antiforgery service to look for the X-CSRF-TOKEN header. To prevent the cross-site request forgery.
    }
   ```
3. Create a PersonModel model:

   ```
    public class PersonModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string DateTime { get; set; }
    }
   ```
4. In the Index.cshtml.cs page. Add a Handler method (**OnPostGetTime**) to handle the Ajax request.

   ```
    namespace RazorSample.Areas.Admin.Pages
    {
        public class IndexModel : PageModel
        {
            public void OnGet()
            {
            }

            public IActionResult OnPostGetTime(string name)
            {
                PersonModel person = new PersonModel
                {
                    Name = name,
                    DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString()
                };
                return new JsonResult(person);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   Then, in the Index.cshtml page, use the following code to display and call the handle method:

   ```
    @page
    @{
        Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    @model RazorSample.Areas.Admin.Pages.IndexModel

    <h2>Admin Index Page</h2>
    <div class="container">

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="text" id="txtName" />
        <input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get Current Time" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#btnGet").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Admin/Index?handler=GetTime",
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                        },
                        data: { "name": $("#txtName").val() }, 
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert("Hello: " + response.name + " .\nCurrent Date and Time: " + response.dateTime);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
   ```

   [**Note**] In the Razor PageModel, the Handler method name is **OnPostGetTime** but here it will be specified as **GetTime** when calling from the Razor HTML Page.

The result like this:

[image]

Reference:

[Razor Pages route and app conventions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Razor Pages Routing](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing)

[Using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-Core-Razor-Pages.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but this won't integrate with the existing application. I ended up just creating a Controller. Razor pages are dumb.